# Is it possible to create a link in a Gatsby .md file using the markdown path, not the eventual url?

Tags: markdown, gatsby

Using gatsby for a blog. Posts are (maybe foolishly, on hindsight) named sequentially. Like post1.md,  post2.md etc. I generate the pages for the posts and then a full url is created. So for example I could end up with:

```
|file     | eventual generated url|
|=========|========================|
|post1.md | https://myblog.com/blog/this-is-foo|
|post2.md | https://myblog.com/blog/wonderful-bar|
```

sometimes i need these posts to link to each other, without being concerned with what the generated url will be. These don't work:

- `[see here](post1.md)` (spits out the raw .md text to the browser)
- `[see here](/blog/post1.md)` (spits out a messy 404 / page not found)

And if I do `[see here](https://myblog.com/this-is-foo)` it would work in production but not in dev. **update** `[see here](/this-is-foo)` works in both environments, but requires me to inspect frontmatter manually and determine what the url path is going to be (or wait for a build, and copy the generated url path).

Is there a solution to this sort of linking that will work at edit time, build time and run time, using just `post1` or similar? If the answer is no, that's fine - I just want to know. (so far, it seems the answer is **NO**, not out of the box).

Comment: Your use case is interesting, I'm surprised (upon an admittedly quick search) there's no official solution for this.

You can write a custom remark plugin that find the links, get its file node, then produce a relative path that will work on both production and dev (i.e `[see here](/this-is-foo)`). Check out the docs on [remark plugins](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/remark-plugin-tutorial/)

Comment: @DerekNguyen - oh wow, thanks for that link - very eye-opening!. Looks like I'd have to extract the code i use to generate urls, so that when i get the file node i can infer the url and replace the node with the html link. Still feels very workaroundish, lol! :o) It'll have to go on my long list of things to play with one day.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
[see here](/this-is-foo)
```

You shouldn't add the `.md` extension to the links, and if you omit the hostname it should work in both your development and production builds.

Comment: Hi Robin yes that is what I ended up doing. My question is badly written: I specificallly wanted a solution where i can just write `post1` and have gatsby understand that I mean "whatever post1 lexically turns into, at the end of the day". I should update my Q. :-/

Comment: Makes sense. This would largely depend on how you're using `gatsby-node.js`, though. You can easily set it up so that URLs are the same as the file names if this helps :)